# SQL query JOIN, many-to-many

Tags: sql-server, join, many-to-many, sql-server-2019

I need small assistance in order to get one query(output) from these tables:

table content

| UUID | Type | CatUUID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ZX5N | image | AB6S |
| ZX5N | image | AB5S |
| ZX5N | doc | TID5 |
| ZX5N | doc | TID6 |

table image

| UUID | Image |
| --- | --- |
| AB6S | test1 |
| AB5S | test2 |

table doc

| UUID | Doc |
| --- | --- |
| TID5 | test3 |
| TID6 | test4 |

table text

| UUID | Body | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ZX5N | text1 | text2 |

the output I want is from text.Body, text.Desc and image.Image

So something like these:

OUTPUT:

| UUID | BODY | Desc | Image | Doc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZX5N | text1 | text2 | test1,test2 | test3,test4 |

In use is MSSQL 2019

I tried to get only "image" first but failed and couldn't pass that, and have no idea how to then add everything in same row with "comma" seperated as seen from the required output

```sql
SELECT text.UUID,text.Body, text.Desc, image.Image
FROM text
LEFT OUTER JOIN content.UUID on text.UUID AND content.Type = 'image'
LEFT OUTER JOIN image on content.CatUUID  =  image.UUID
```

Comment: MySql <> SqlServer - please tag appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `STRING_AGG()` for this:

```
SELECT t.UUID, t.Body, t.[Desc],
  Image = STRING_AGG(i.[Image], ','),
  Doc   = STRING_AGG(d.Doc, ',')
FROM dbo.[text] AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.content AS c
  ON t.UUID = c.UUID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[image] AS i
  ON c.[Type] = 'image' AND c.CatUUID = i.UUID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.doc AS d
  ON c.[Type] = 'doc' AND c.CatUUID = d.UUID
GROUP BY t.UUID, t.Body, t.[Desc];
```

Working example [in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TpcSAidu).

Also, try to use `[fewer] [reserved] [words]`, which require delimiting that makes them `[harder] [to] [read]`.

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm.

As for the delimiting, thanks for the tip, will be more careful on that one